# Javascript (Angularjs) websocket with promises?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use Angularjs in a project. I use $q.all with multiple request from $http, It's work.

In new case, I use websocket, but I don't know how to use promises with websocket.

$http return promises, but websocket is not.

Websocket Example: (it's not real code)

I send pack id is 1000, and I reviced pack id is 2000.

```
websocket.send(1000);

websocket.onMessage(data) {
  if (data.id == 2000) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

I went to use Promises with websocket, it's possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could setup a basic request/response [reactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern) and wrap that with promises.

Setting up the reactor:

```js
var callbacks = {};
websocket.onmessage = function(event) {
  var data = angular.fromJson(event.data);
  if (angular.isDefined(callbacks[data.request_id])) {
    var callback = callbacks[data.request_id];
    delete callbacks[data.request_id];
    callback.resolve(data);
  } else {
    $log.error("Unhandled message: %o", data);
  }
};
```

The request function:

```js
var requestId = 0;
$scope.getRequestId = function() {
  return requestId++;
};

$scope.request = function(data) {
  var request = {
    request_id: $scope.getRequestId(),
    data: data
  };
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  callbacks[request.request_id] = deferred;
  websocket.send(angular.toJson(request));
  return deferred.promise.then(function(response) {
    request.response = response;
    return response;
  });
};
```

An example use case might be:

```js
$scope.request("My Request").then(function(response) {
  // do something with response
});
```

You could also make use of `onerror` and `onclose` to do `$q.reject` where appropriate so that websocket errors could make it back to the promise.

Here is a simple websocket echo example using the above technique: http://plnkr.co/edit/ORSqXz07I9cLspZQg1iM?p=preview

Comment: Thank for your help, But I can't change server protocol, so i can't use 'request_id'. In my case, the protocol maybe like this: send command 1000 then receive command 2000; send command 1002 then receive 2000 and 2001. So I have two problem, I can't distinguish receive command from send twice command. And I can't use a map to mapping receive and send command.

Comment: @allyusd Yeah, that's tricky.  Promises need an "final state" in order to work properly.  If you still wanted to wrap multiple messages packaged as a response to a sent command, you could potentially use [`$q notify()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-deferred-api) ending with `resolve()` or `reject()` based on your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot integrate promises with WebSockets, as the WebSocket API already uses callbacks:

```
socket = new WebSocket(host);
socket.onopen = function() {
    document.getElementById("m1-status").innerHTML = 'CONNECTING...';
};
socket.onclose = function() {
    document.getElementById("m1-status").innerHTML = 'FINISHED';
};
socket.onerror = function() {
    document.getElementById("m1-status").innerHTML = 'ERROR - Please refresh this page';
};
socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
try { 
    console.log(data);
...
```